# Exporting test results from TFS to Excel

Tags: test-management, mtm, tfs

I have a test plan in MTM, now I have run (executed) all the test cases of that plan and have the results in MTM (and TFS).

How can I export the test execution results to an excel or any other type of document? *(as I need to create share the result of all test cases with management)*

Answer (score 2):

There could be a number of other ways but the best I could found is to follow these steps:

1. Launch MTM and navigate to "Analyze Test Runs".
2. Select tests based on "View" and "Start date range".
3. Use *Ctrl+c* to copy the records.
4. Open Excel and use *Ctrl+v* to paste the records.

You should be able to select additional columns by right clicking the header row before step 3 above.

I hope it is helpful.